# Vue: Nuxt: content not showing inside nuxt-child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My page structure is:

```
pages/
--| music/
-----| index.vue
-----| rock.vue
-----| pop.vue
```

My file code is:

#### music/index.vue

```
<template>
   <div> 
      <nuxt-link :to="localePath('music-rock')">Rock</nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="localePath('music-pop')">Pop</nuxt-link>
   </div>

   <div>
      <nuxt-child/>
   </div>
</template>
```

#### music/rock.vue

```
<template>
   <div></div>
</template>
```

But when on `music` route and click on **Rock** link, the page opens entirely with rock.vue content, instead of just inside the `nuxt-child` element.

What I am doing wrong?

*(And how can I set a default route, since it's a tab system?)*

Ps: `localePath` is part of i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

I had to

- move `/music/index.vue` to `/music.vue`
- create a `/music/index.vue` with the default content for the `nuxt-child`

It's working now.